# Raspberry Pi Pin 17 Displaying Abnormal Behavior

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I found that GPIO 17 (there was a switch wired up to it) had abnormal behavior.

I have wired up a hall effect sensor on pin 18, but when it goes low (it is high when not detected, low when detected), an event is detected on pin 17.

I am using a pull-down resistor for the switch wired to pin 17 and I don't use either a pull-down or pull-up resistor for the hall effect sensor pin. I am using `RPi.GPIO` events to detect when they go low or go high.

I am also using the Pi 4.

I am wondering why this is occurring and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add a circuit diagram and the code

Comment: @jsotola I updated the question and I will add a circuit diagram

Comment: pin 17 or gpio 17?

Comment: It is GPIO 17 for the switch

Comment: Doe the switch work as it should? if 18 is high, toggling 17 works, similarly when 18 is low? it's just the transition of 18 also triggers 17 - both rising and falling?